# Getting error during programatically add to cart product

Tags: magento2

Giving below error during add to cart programmatically in  Magento 2 enterprise edition. Community version it is properly working.

Error:
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): ampromo_cart is unknown type

Using below code for add to cart product

```
$productId = 2232;
$params = array(
        'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
        'product' => $productId, //product Id
        'qty'   =>1 //quantity of product                
    ); 

//Load the product based on productID   
$_product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);       
$this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
$this->cart->save();
```

Error screenshot
[image]

I am using below custom script for add to cart product programatically:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require '../app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);


$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$productId = 2459;
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$cart = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');  
$formKey = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey')->getFormKey();  

$params = array(
                    'form_key' => $formKey,
                    'product' => $productId, //product Id
                    'qty'   =>1
                    );
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
```

Comment: You're using Amasty Free gift extension ?

Comment: Yes we are using amasty extension and I have already try to disable Amasty_Rules extension but not getting success

Comment: Can you please disable that for some time and then try once ? Please disable bannerlite extension there

Comment: Still getting error

Comment: same error you're getting there ?

Comment: yes, getting same error

Comment: can you please remove your generated directory and then run setup:upgrade command there and then check ?

Comment: I have disabled all amasty modules and  run all Magento commands and also remove generated folder also but still getting error

Comment: Can you please share full error with me like in this file and line no etc ?

Comment: Edit question with error and script that was I am using

Comment: Can you please check your marketing cart price rules ? Or try with different product ID once.

Comment: Can you disable this plugin and then check **Amasty_Rules** ?

Comment: I have already tried to disable all amasty modules also.